# JSON is not handled properly in react and not saved in the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having an issue while getting JSON data.

Code having the issue is:

```
constructor(props, context) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {anchorEl: null, 
            showJoin: false,
            classDetailsInfo: {
                classpic: [],
                reviews: []
            },
            onError: false
        }
    };

componentDidMount = () => {
        const queryString = window.location.search;
        const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
        const id = urlParams.get('id')

        console.log("this is my id: " + id)
        if(urlParams.has('id') && (id !== '')) {
            this.setState({userInfo: ClassDataUseCase.getClassDetails(id)})
            this.setState({onError: false})
            console.log(this.state.userInfo)
        } else {
            this.setState({onError: true})
        }
    }
```

the `ClassDataUseCase` is just a "abstraction layer to grab the proper data.

```
class ClassDataUseCase {

    static getClassDetails(id) {
        var jsonClasses = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(ClassDetailsData.Classes));
        console.log(jsonClasses)
        for(let k=0;k< jsonClasses.length;k++){
            if(jsonClasses[k].id === id){
                console.log(jsonClasses[k])
              return jsonClasses[k];
            }
        }
        console.log("We are f***ed up")
    }
}
```

The JSON is properly returned but when I try to check the content of the `this.state.classDetailsInfo`, I just got `undefined` in the console. I thought at first that I have to run through a `JSON.parse` but it's failing as well.

I am probably not saving it properly in the state.

Comment: In the code you posted you set the `userInfo`, not the `classDetailsInfo`. The syntax seems right.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why calling react setState method doesn't mutate the state immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782948/why-calling-react-setstate-method-doesnt-mutate-the-state-immediately)

Answer (score 0):

As @k-wasilewski points out in the comments, you are setting state of `userInfo`, not `classDetailsInfo`. So depending on whether this was just a typo in your question, it may explain the issue you're trying to solve.

If, however, you're actually trying to check the value of `userInfo`, there is a potential issue with these lines:

```
this.setState({userInfo: ClassDataUseCase.getClassDetails(id)})
this.setState({onError: false})
console.log(this.state.userInfo)
```

`setState` changes may not be applied immediately, so it is possible that the `console.log` is being invoked before setState is finished. You can pass a callback to `setState` to guarantee the order of execution:

```
this.setState({userInfo: ClassDataUseCase.getClassDetails(id)}, () => console.log('updated userInfo:', this.state.userInfo))
```